# Remove time from dynamic DateTime dropdown in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core dropdown using razor to get items dynamically:

```
<select padding= 10px asp-for="SelectedDate"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AvailableDates))"
        onchange = "this.form.submit();" >

    <option>Please select one</option>

</select>
```

The problem is how do I remove the time section when displaying the values?

I have heard about using [DateTime Formatting Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720651(VS.71).aspx), but how would I use them with razor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format dates for select list:

```
new SelectList(Model.AvailableDates.Select(date => date.ToString("d")))
```

Comment: This worked fantastically. Thanks. I will mark as answer. +1

Comment: @JamesHyland, super, consider to also accept the answer :)